# Intern js for functional using selenium Grid 2

Tags: selenium, functional-testing, intern

**Here is my situation:**

(I only want the functional testing aspect from intern.)

- I have selenium standalone running as a hub on one machine.
- I have selenium standalone running as a node on a few machines - win7,win8,osx 10.8, etc. each with chrome, firefox, safari, IE.
- All these machines live on the same network - they can access each other.
- I am running intern (intern-runner) configured for functional tests.

Currently when I run the intern-runner, [take for example -- on the osx 10.8] I see the 
proper browser being launched, but the URL is:

`http://some.ip.addr:port/__intern/client.html?baseUrl=%2F&config=tests%2Fintern.js&reporters=webdriver&sessionId=8e442817-1f41-4690-9af5-e0a513cb17b1`

**the problem is --**

- i cannot use the `__intern` in the path -- the url that i can use is purely this:

`http://some.ip.addr:port/`

**Question is:**

1) how do i configure the url that is entered in the remotely executed browser?

2) how do i configure each segment of that url -- ie - the params, the `client.html` segment and the `__intern` segment.

**I've tried...**

setting in intern.js: `proxy, proxyUrl, proxyType=direct`.

**Let me re-iterate:**

1) I only want functional testing -- no unit testing - i already have that part covered.

2) I've performed exhaustive searches, have read all of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Intern runs a server that is responsible for serving code and resources that are loaded by the browser. This server provides the `/__intern/` path. You cannot just not use this server when you are using the runner, that is not a supported operation. There are [instructions on how to proxy properly](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-Intern-to-unit-test-Ajax-calls) to the Intern server in the wiki. This has nothing to do with using Selenium Grid.

Comment: Based on your response, it sounds as though I must use intern's web server to fulfill the browser requests.  In other words, even though my webapp is written on top of Express.js and therefore node.js, I must use intern's server?  Please clarify.  I have no problem purchasing support from sitepen, but i want to make sure that what I want to accomplish is feasible before making a payment.  I do not want to have a consulting session only to find out that intern does not fit my needs.

Comment: Also, I did take a look at the suggested link - however, this documentation seems to be in the context of unit testing.  I am interested in the functional testing - in particular, automating it.  Can you suggest an other documentation?  Thanks in advance!